# Spark Streaming directory fills disk

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a stream job which is intended to run continuously with a single step which uses `mapWithState` and therefore requires checkpointing to be configured. I set it up with a local directory as this is only running on a single node at this stage.

I'm observing that the checkpoint directory grows quickly and continuously. Over the course of a few days it grows to over a million files and exhausts the inodes on the disk.

### Questions:

1. Is this expected behavior?
2. Assuming not, how can I isolate what might be causing the snapshots not to be pruned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that checkpointing was enable by `sparkContext.checkpoint(checkpointDir)` rather than `sparkStreamingContext.checkpoint(checkpointDir)`.

The former was enough to make Spark run the stateful stream instead of complaining that checkpointing was not enabled, but the appropriate logic for streaming checkpoints was not being called because `sparkStreamingContext.checkpointDir` was null.